# How to apply toStringAsFixed() to a templated value class member?

Tags: dart, templates

Say we have a template class of type T that defines value being of that class T

```dart
class BmsEditableValue<T> extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Value to be edited
  final T? value;
}
```

I wan to apply `toStringAsFixed()` on value when it is a `double`, but the following makes `toStringAsFixed()` not being defined:

```
value! is double
                ? value!.toFixedString(decimals!)
                : value;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did that:

```
 (value! as double).toStringAsFixed(decimals!)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a local variable to allow automatic type promotion to occur:

```dart
Object? v = value;
var result = (v is double)
  ? v.toStringAsFixed(...)
  : value;
```

Note that `v` must be declared as `Object` or `dynamic` and not as `T` because [Dart will not automatically perform type promotion across types that are not statically known to be related](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/2047#issuecomment-782602222).